# Cannot build C++ code using lapack

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, matrix, lapack

I wrote a simple code to test boost and lapack
But it doesn't work well

My code :

```
#include  < iostream>
#include < boost/numeric/bindings/traits/ublas_matrix.hpp>
#include < boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include < boost/numeric/bindings/lapack/syev.hpp>
#include < boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;
namespace lapack = boost::numeric::bindings::lapack;

int main() {
  ublas::matrix<double> A(3,3);
  ublas::vector<double> B(3);
  A(0,0)=1;
  A(1,1)=2;
  A(2,2)=4;
  A(0,1)=.5;
  A(0,2)=.25;
  A(1,2)=.3;

  lapack::syev('V','L',A,B);
  std::cout << A << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My option g++ to build on ubuntu 10.04
g++ -llapack test.cpp

It's error :

no matching function for call to ‘syev(char....... )‘

If there's not "lapack::syev('V','L',A,B);" It's build okay!
**Plz Help me !!**

Answer (score 1):

Please install the `libboost-all-dev` package.

Comment: I have installed all package about boost and lapack.I copy folder "boost-numeric-bindings" to /usr/include/boost/numeric and g++ can recognize header from lapack.But it can't call function from lapack !!!!!!!!

Comment: Do you have `liblapack-dev` installed?